# How to mount the redux-form further down in a nested state structure?

Tags: redux, redux-form

I am stuck here on how to mount the redux-form reducer at the right place.

I have this initial state for a namespace called person (among many other namespaces in the app), something like this:

```
{
  personList: [],
  creatingNewPerson: false,
  newPerson: {}
}
```

the newPerson state is a form. How can I tell to have a redux-reducer acting on the newPerson state alone?

sure, you could do something like

```
combineReducers({
  person: personReducer, // that's a reducer using the above json
  newPerson: formReducer // import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
})
```

but that's not the structure I am after. The state for the newPerson will be managed outside of the person state. But I want it to be managed inside.

It should be possible when the states redux-form is managing are JSON serializable.

How can this be achieved? Hope I made myself clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `redux-form` seems quite opinionated in this particular case, and [the general sentiment](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/Reducer.md/) [from the documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) is quite clear: You should mount the `formReducer` at the root of your state tree under the `form` -key.

The reason for this is simple: the `formReducer` will handle the state for all of your forms, not just the new person form. So the state will look something like this:

```
{
  person: { ... person-related state ... },
  form: {
    NewPersonForm: { ... new person form state ... },
    SomeOtherForm: { ... some other form state ... },
    ...
    NthAdditionalForm: { ... nth additional form state ... }
  }
}
```

This means that if you'd want to position the state for each form nested inside the reducer the resulting object will end up in, you'd have to add in instances of `formReducer` in multiple locations, which would unnecessarily complicate your state.

My recommendation: Eat your proverbial greens in this case and just insert the `formReducer` in the default location, because that way you'll get the enjoy the power of `redux-form` without any additional headaches.

**Now, after reading the above, if you're still dead set on actually mounting the `formReducer` somewhere deep within the damp and dark mazes of your state tree**, you could do something like the following:

```
combineReducers({
  persons: combineReducers({
    person: personReducer,
    newPerson: formReducer
  }),
  other: otherReducer,
  ...
  some: someReducer
})
```

Then you also need to pass a `getFormState` to each `reduxForm` -wrapped component so they know where you hid their state:

```
const getFormState = state => {
  // return the slice of state where we hid formReducer
  return state.persons.newPerson
}

reduxForm({ getFormState })(SomeForm)
```

Doing this is something I cannot, with good conscience, recommend, but should produce the results you want (in addition to possible nasty side-effects if you ever add more than this one form to your app).

Hope this helps!

Comment: damp and dark mazes? :) i don't think so. when you come from clojurescript/re-frame you will see that app state is grouped by namespace which is a good, modular approach. but yeah, i reckon now that redux-form is kinda very opinionated.

your solution works but still, isn't 100% what i am after. because it adds another nesting level i find not necessary: having persons, then a person and newPerson entry. the json gets too deep.

Comment: Maybe my choice of words was a touch dramatic, but essentially what you're looking to do is to mix one reducer within the slice of state managed by another reducer. AFAIK redux does not support one reducer being nested within another; you can only bundle them under their own namespaces with `combineReducers`.

So, if you have a reducer that manages `personList`, that reducer cannot also house `formReducer` within its state.

Comment: fair enough, understand now and respect that redux-form is very opinionated when it comes to the app state structure. all good now.